# How to draw coverage area on Google Map?

Tags: google-maps

Basically I have some school catchment map that I would like to put on Google Map. I have done some research but it seems that we can only draw polylines. For example, I like to draw the red line from the [attached image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7i8klbmdbbhkj1z/van_school_catchment.png) onto Google Map, how do I do that? Any tip or point of direction would be very appreciated!!

Comment: I would recommend start doing this with [polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple). You should be able to find out the coordinates to create this shape; it may not be a simple shape, but this is very doable.

Comment: Thank you @admdrew for the suggestion. About finding out the coordinates, I can get them from google map by pointing the mouse position to there, is there any other way to do it i.e. existing geo database? Thanks.

Comment: That I am not sure about, sorry. Good luck!